# Allow use of both user.github.io domain and custom domain

Tags: github, dns, github-pages

I am using github pages and want to be able to use both the `user.github.io` domain and my custom domain `example.com`. I have successfully set up a custom domain, but I don't want to be redirected to it when going to `user.github.io`. Is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, if a custom domain is deployed, your `user.github.io` domain will always redirect to the defined custom domain